# Splitting Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string value which is passed in to my javascript file which is like:

```
"["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e","a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a","f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]"
```

I want to split the GUID by each comma.

So I was doing something like this:

```
var string = "["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e","a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a","f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]";

var array = string.split(',');
```

When I index into the array I am getting the results:

```
array[0] = "["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e""
array[1] = ""a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a""
array[2] = ""f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]"
```

This is pretty close to what I need but what is the best way to get rid of the extra "" that get added as well as the `[` from `array[0]` and the `]` from `array[2]`

Comment: Have you already tried the method `.replace()`?

Comment: JSON.parse(string) results in an array of strings

Comment: You could 'replace' method of string , repace all quotes  "string".replace(/\"/g, 'new value');

Comment: @Nico: That was an *answer*, not a comment.

Comment: Yup it was. But seemed to short to be an answer

Comment: @Nico: [And yet...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29649981/157247) Short is fine, provided it clearly answers the question / solves the problem. In fact, short is good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about JSON?

```
JSON.parse('["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e","a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a","f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]')
```

Comment: This will work really nicely for me - Thanks - will accept when I can

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `"`, `[`, and `]` prior to splitting:

```
var array = str.replace(/["[\]]/g, "").split(",");
```

`/["[\]]/g` is a regular expression defining a character class that contains the characters `"`, `[`, and `]`, meaning "any of these characters here". It replaces anything matching that with a blank string.

Example:

```js
var str = "[\"244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e\",\"a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a\",\"f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9\"]";
var array = str.replace(/["[\]]/g, "").split(",");
array.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  snippet.log("array[" + index + "]: " + entry);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `[]`, remove commas & space, split:

```
var string = "[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\"]";

var arr = string.substr(1, string.length - 2).replace(/[\"\s]/g, "").split(",");

alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer [Splitting Array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649892/splitting-array-in-javascript#answer-29649981) is correct it begs a little more explanation.

Given the string:

`"["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e","a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a","f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]"`

This string follows a common JSON array format http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#dfn-array :

> An array structure is represented as square brackets surrounding zero
>   or more values. Values are separated by commas. In JSON, an array is
>   an ordered sequence of zero or more values.

In the example string each object is actually a string as it is surrounded by the `"` or `'` marker. To parse a JSON string to an object you simply have to call:

`var jsonObject = JSON.parse(string);`

This will result in an object array of strings. Which can then be iterated, or managed in a common JavaScript `Array` fashion.

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is via eval() function without any librarys.

```
var arr = '["244aac9a-0833-40a2-b8e9-9bef89562b2e","a392913d-9a17-4c30-ba99-f9ad9745fa0a","f5eca9a9-c6ef-4abb-b54c-134271d69cd9"]';

var arrObj = eval(arr);
console.log(arrObj.length) //length is 3
```

Also wrap the string value in single quote(') instead of double quote(").